# Resizing div to width of contained images

Tags: css, resize

So I'm creating a gallery which scrolls left to right. What I want to do is have the div holding the images resize to the combined width of the images so that you cannot scroll past the final image into nothingness. At the moment I have a fixed width. Replacing this with inline-block doesn't work (maybe because the 70% width from .country_holder is forcing block behavior?) This is my current code:

```
    <ul>
    <li class="country_holder" id="c_scotland">
      <div class ="g_title" id="g_scotland"><h6>Scotland</h6></div>
      <div class="gallery_holder">
        <ul>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-1.jpg" height="150"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-2.jpg" height="150"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-3.jpg" height="150"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-4.jpg" height="150"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-5.jpg" height="150"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-6.jpg" height="150"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-7.jpg" height="150"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-8.jpg" height="150"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-9.jpg" height="150"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-10.jpg" height="150"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-11.jpg" height="150"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-12.jpg" height="150"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-13.jpg" height="150"></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.country_holder {
  position:relative;
  margin-top:2rem;
  margin-bottom:2rem;
  width:70%;
  left:18.5%;
  display:block;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow:-moz-scrollbars-horizontal;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.gallery_holder{
  width:4000px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
  background-color:none;
}

li.gallery_img{
  padding-right:2px;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  height:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure CSS solution:

```css
.country_holder {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  left: 18.5%;
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-horizontal;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gallery_holder {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: none;
}

li.gallery_img {
  padding-right: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="country_holder" id="c_scotland">
    <div class="g_title" id="g_scotland">
      <h6>Scotland</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_holder">
      <ul>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-1.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-2.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-3.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-4.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-5.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-6.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-7.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-8.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-9.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-10.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-11.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-12.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-13.jpg" height="150"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or you may want to only scroll the images, not the title:

```css
.country_holder {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  left: 18.5%;
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gallery_holder {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.gallery_holder ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: none;
}

li.gallery_img {
  padding-right: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="country_holder" id="c_scotland">
    <div class="g_title" id="g_scotland">
      <h6>Scotland</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_holder">
      <ul>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-1.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-2.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-3.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-4.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-5.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-6.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-7.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-8.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-9.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-10.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-11.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-12.jpg" height="150"></li>
        <li class="gallery_img"><img src="Assets/Images/Gallery/ScotlandGallery-13.jpg" height="150"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Scott Glad that helped you, please read [when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to know what you should do when someone answers your question :)

Comment: Thanks again - didn't realise this!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```js
var gallery_holder_width = 0;
jQuery('.gallery_holder ul li.gallery_img').each(function(i, el) {
  gallery_holder_width += jQuery(el).width() + 2 /* padding-right */;
});
jQuery('.gallery_holder').width(gallery_holder_width);
```

```css
.country_holder {
  position:relative;
  margin-top:2rem;
  margin-bottom:2rem;
  width:70%;
  left:18.5%;
  display:block;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow:-moz-scrollbars-horizontal;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.gallery_holder{
  width:4000px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
  background-color:none;
}
.gallery_holder ul{
  padding: 0
}
.gallery_holder ul li.gallery_img{
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset; /* added just for display */
  padding-right:2px;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="country_holder" id="c_scotland">
      <div class ="g_title" id="g_scotland"><h6>Scotland</h6></div>
      <div class="gallery_holder">
        <ul>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 50px"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 150px"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 100px"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 80px"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 120px"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 200px"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 50px"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 30px"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 40px"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 50px"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 90px"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 140px"></li>
          <li class="gallery_img" style="width: 70px"></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your response - this looks great, but I'm going to run with the CSS version. All the best!